# Combine: Outputting Decoded Data from URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher

Tags: swift, combine

Currently, I am using this `Combine` code to fetch data from an API:

```
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            // fetch on background thread
            .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            // receive response on main thread
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            // ensure there is data
            .tryMap { (data, response) in
                guard
                    let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
                }
                NetworkTimer.shared.stop()
                return data
            }
            // decode JSON data to WeatherAPIDecoder
            .decode(type: WeatherAPIDecoder.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            // Handle results
            .sink { (result) in
                // will return success or failure
                //                NSLog("completion: \(result)")
            } receiveValue: { [self] (weatherAPI) in
                // if success, will return wsWeather
                // here you can update your view
                //                NSLog("value: \(wsWeather)")
                processWeatherData(weatherAPI)
            }
            // After receiving response, the URLSession is no longer needed & we can cancel the publisher
            .cancel()
```

This works fine, but now I need to make two network requests, one for current data and one for historical data. I would then like to await the results of these two requests and put them together into one struct, and I can't wrap my head around how to change the `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher` to return just the decoded data. I intend to call the `dataTaskPublisher` from another function with an Async Await and then create one object from the data and pass it on. Any assistance would be appreciated. This has to be for iOS 14+.

Edit:

I don't have the code together yet, my idea is something along these lines:

func update() {
async let (current, _) = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: currentURL)
async let (historical, _) = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: historicalURL)

guard let combinedData = CombinedData(current: current, historical: historical) else { throw error }
...
}

Comment: async/await and Combine are sort of opposites. Can you show more of what you're talking about?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MergeMany` publisher to achieve that.

```
let requestA = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "")!)
let requestB = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "")!)

Publishers.MergeMany([requestA, requestB]).collect().tryMap {...}
```

You may also want to have a look at this blog post (not mine).

https://mattcomi.tumblr.com/post/627300779277025280/waiting-on-multiple-publishers-using-mergemany